# Connect with facebook using PHP SDK in codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, authentication

Im implementing facebook's PHP SDK for authentication [here](http://skillpaper.com/exams). I've searched over net and found lots of tutorial on that. like [Using Facebook PHP SDK 3 with CodeIgniter](http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2012/04/using-facebook-php-sdk-3-with-codeigniter-2-1/)

i've modified base_facebook.php to return **www.skillpaper.com/auth/fb_register** in

```
$this->facebook->getLoginUrl()
```

when i click "Connect with Facebook" in login modal  and facebook auth popup appears its successfully redirect to my given url. i.e **www.skillpaper.com/auth/fb_register**

and my code is like in auth controller:

```
public function fb_register(){

        $userId = $this->facebook->getUser();
        if($userId != 0){
            // Get user's data and print it
            $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            var_dump($user);
        }else{ echo "No user";}
}
```

i'm getting "No user" every time!
What am i missing? I don't want to use any JS API for this. any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please Download the Facebook PHP SDK From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/
Now Put src folder into application/controller folder.
Call into controller any function like this :-

```
    require 'src/facebook.php';
    $appId = FBAPPID;
    $secretkey = FBSECRETKEY;

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appId,
  'secret' => $secretkey,
    ));
    $fb['facebook']=$facebook;
    $facebook_user = $facebook->getUser();
    $fb['facebook_user']=$facebook_user;
    if ($facebook_user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    //$fb['logoutUrl'] = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $facebook_user = null;
    $this->load->view('Your Page');

  }
    }else {
        $data['loginUrl'] = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'         => 'user_about_me,email,user_birthday,friends_birthday,publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access'              
        ));
        $this->load->view('Your Page');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I'm already using that SDK in my project.
I think im missing something in the redirect_url. Facebook does redirect in my given URL with a CODE=afa213131@w3423213133dsfasdfadf in the URL. But on that page(redirect URL) i can't get $facebook->getUser(); after he/she has given permission.